# Map generated in Cloud-based Maps Styling v3 does not work properly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After switching from maps **v2** to **v3** (due to **Cloud-based Maps Styling**) I get this result in **Light Mode** (as in the screenshot)

The map is as if covered by some black block (but this place is clickable -> maybe the phone is breaking something graphically)

If I change to Dark Mode on my phone it works fine

Map Fragment in Activity

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    map:mapId="@string/map_id"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

[image]

Can something be done about it?

Comment: Can you file an issue regarding this in Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=541018&template=1201436)? So they can further check what the issue is. Make sure to add necessary details to reproduce the problem